# Find the sum of the Series using taylor series expansion or any other method

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

Find:

$\frac{1}{2\pi}\biggl(\frac{\pi^3}{1!.3}-\frac{\pi^5}{3!.5}+\frac{\pi^7}{5!.7}-\frac{\pi^9}{7!.9}+.......\biggr)=$

I tied a lot to solve this question by relating it to the taylor series expansion of sin x.But just couldnt get it.

Comment: Please fix your MathJax, as we can't see your sum :)

Comment: Saying "I tried a lot..." does not show us what you tried. What if you were on the right path? (wink wink) C'mon, help us help you.

Comment: Hint: think of derivatives or integrals of your favorite trig functions.

Comment: Try differentiating $(\sin x)/x$.

Comment: That's $$\frac1{2\pi}\int^\pi_0x\,\sin x\,dx.$$

Comment: @Professor Vector ...How can we say that...Do we use any particular technique to arrive there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have that
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{x^{2n+1}(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+1)\cdot(2n-1)!}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{2n+3}(-1)^n}{(2n+3)\cdot(2n+1)!}=\int_{0}^{x}z\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{z^{2n+1}(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\,dz $$
so the given expression equals
$$ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}x \sin(x)\,dx \stackrel{\text{symmetry}}{=} \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{\pi}{2}\sin(x)\,dx=\frac{1}{2\pi}\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}\cdot 2=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2}}$$
since $\sin(x)=\sin(\pi -x)$ and $\int_{0}^{\pi}\sin(x)\,dx = 2$.